# Add rows to Single product Additional information table in WooCommerce 3.6

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add a row to Single product Additional information table.

[image: Screenshot]

Actually is there any hooks or filter to do this? I have searched the hook but can't figure out the solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since WooCommerce **version 3.6**, you can use `woocommerce_display_product_attributes` filter hook in this simple way, to add custom label/value pairs in "Additional Information" table *(tab)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'custom_product_additional_information', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_additional_information( $product_attributes, $product ) {
    // First row
    $product_attributes[ 'attribute_' . 'custom-one' ] = array(
        'label' => __('Label One'),
        'value' => __('Value 1'),
    );

    // Second row
    $product_attributes[ 'attribute_' . 'custom-two' ] = array(
        'label' => __('Label Two'),
        'value' => __('Value 2'),
    );

    return $product_attributes;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and work.

[image]

Comment: This works perfect thanks! Is there a way to echo a custom field for the product into the Value 1 field? 

This is how I'm currently outputting it <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Size', true ); ?>

Comment: is there a way to change it from a table to a custom html element of my choice?